# Correct typography for the name of an event

Tags: formatting, essay

When you write the title of a book, you put it in italics. What about the title of an event, such as the Super Bowl or the World Cup?  Of everything I looked at, this has the most information, but there is no mention of events.

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/underline-or-italicize-book-titles/

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Can you provide an example of what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: You're asking about a *style* issue, and the answer (if one is possible) is therefore heavily dependent on the kind of writing you're doing and the way it might be published. Most ***style guides*** will provide some guidance. PS you don't have to put the title of a book in italics; while common practice, this again is a matter of *style*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of events are generally just capitalized, just like most other proper nouns. There is no special typographical convention for them that is regularly followed.